# Library(terra) error from Extract values from SpatRaster; R

Tags: r, extract, raster

I am basic in R and this code should be working although I get an error on this part of the code.
Although I tried adding a "simple" method it seems not to solve the issue

```
library(terra)
# create SpatRast for all SM files
imgSM <- rast(sub("NDVI_cropped.tif","SM_cropped.tif",files))
xy <- cbind(x,y)

valNDVI <- extract(img, xy)0.0001 # extract and convert DN to NDVI
#Error: unexpected numeric constant in "valNDVI <- extract(img, xy)0.0001"

valSM <- extract(imgSM, xy) # extract SM
#Error in UseMethod("extract") : 
#  no applicable method for 'extract' applied to an object of class "SpatRaster"
```

Comment: It looks like you're new to SO; welcome to the community! If you want great answers quickly, it's best to make your question reproducible. This includes sample data like the output from `dput(head(dataObject))` and any libraries you are using. Check it out: [making R reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269).

Answer (score 2):

This error

```
valNDVI <- extract(img, xy)0.0001 
#Error: unexpected numeric constant in "valNDVI <- extract(img, xy)0.0001"
```

Is probably obvious when you see it. It should be without the trailing 0.0001

```
valNDVI <- extract(img, xy)
```

This one

```
valSM <- extract(imgSM, xy)
#Error in UseMethod("extract") : 
#  no applicable method for 'extract' applied to an object of class"SpatRaster"
```

Suggests that you have loaded another package that has an `extract` methods and masks the method from `terra` (probably the `tidyr` package). It is good practice to only load packages you need (avoid `library(tidyverse)`), and you can also prepend the package name to avoid conflicts. Like this:

```
valSM <- terra::extract(imgSM, xy)
```